# Getting the number of layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

There does not seem to be a command to get the number of layers in the map, or am I missing it?

One way to count the layers would be:

```
Object.keys(map._layers).length
```

Or is there another preferred way? For instance, I would be interested in finding out how many vectors or how many basemaps have been added to the map, and I am not sure how to achieve that via the above snippet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leaflet's public API has an [`eachLayer` method for the `Map` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-eachlayer):

```
let i = 0;
map.eachLayer(function(){ i += 1; });
console.log('Map has', i, 'layers.');
```

Please note that `eachLayer` will properly iterate through layers inside a `L.LayerGroup`, `L.FeatureGroup` and `L.GeoJson`.

Also note that `.getLayers()` works for `LayerGroup` (and `FeatureGroup` and `GeoJson`), but not for `L.Map`.

Usage of "private" properties and methods like `_layers` or `_leaflet_id` or `_latlng` is discouraged.

Comment: seems iffy though, `_layers` could be checked without looping over and over and over again. seems like a gap in their design

Answer (score 0):

If you mean of features in a layer try:

`console.log(myRoadLayer.getLayers().length + " Features in the Roads Layer");`

If you mean basemaps like "Aerial", "Streets", "Topo" you define what you want in your map. Likewise overlay layers like "Roads", "Water", "Parcels" are also defined in the creation of your map.